# Connecting Issue AWS IoT Websocket with Cognito Auth Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-iot

I have created an app with Cognito Authenticated User Pool. To connect AWS IoT, I have attached following IAM Role Policy to Cognito_UserPoolAuth_Role;

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iot:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

In addition, I have attached a Principal Policy (with each Cognito Identity of User) to IoT Devices’s policies in AWS IoT. General format of IoT Device Policy in such below;

```
{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "iot:Connect"
                ],
                "Resource": `arn:aws:iot:${region}:${accountId}:client/${certificateId}`
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "iot:Publish",
                    "iot:Receive"
                ],
                "Resource": `arn:aws:iot:${region}:${accountId}:topic/${foo/bar/${certificateId}}/*`
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "iot:Subscribe",
                ],
                "Resource": `arn:aws:iot:${region}:${accountId}:topicfilter/${foo/bar/${certificateId}}/#`
            }
        ]
    }
```

Websocket Code in iOS;

```
self.iotDataManager.connectUsingWebSocket( withClientId: UUID().uuidString, cleanSession:true, statusCallback: self.mqttEventCallback(_:))
```

Problem is, if IoT Device Policy’s Connect Reosurce is remained as above, Websocket Connection from iOS App, is giving following error continuously;

```
MQTT session error, code: 2
closing encoder stream.
closing decoder stream.
MQTT session closed.
Trying to reconnect to session.
Websocket did open and is Connected.
streamsThread is still running. Waiting for it to exit.
Signaling runloopSemaphore
Initializing MQTTEncoder and MQTTDecoder streams
opening encoder stream.
opening decoder stream.
MQTTEncoderStatus = 0
MQTTSessionStatus = 0
WebSocket closed with code:1001 with reason:Stream end encountered
```

If i have made following adjustment in Connect Resource as below then Websocket connected.

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iot: ${region}:${accountId}:client/${certificateId}”,
    "arn:aws:iot: :${region}:${accountId}:client/${iot:ClientId}"
  ]
}
```

This way is enough Secure? Because it accepts any clientID who had certificates. Is there someway to connect AWS IoT Websocket from App, without adding ${iot:ClientId} into Connect Resource of the IoT Policy?